# Script is changing values?

Tags: r

I have a problem with my R-script, as it changes the input values when I try to treat the data.

```
items <- dataset 

Date    A    B    C    D 
1-2010  0    0    0    1 
2-2010  0    0    1    2 
3-2010  1    1    0    0  

data_test <- NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(items)) {
  col <- ts(items[,i])
  fit1 <- auto.arima(col, trace=TRUE)
  fcast <- forecast(fit1,h=12, level=c(90,95))
data_test <- cbind(data_test, fcast$lower)
}
```

But if I write col I get:

```
Date    A    B    C    D  
1-2010  3    4    3    3  
2-2010  3    3    2    3 
3-2010  4    3    3    3
```

I think it is because of the ts function (that it needs at least one observation), but how can I avoid/get around it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I couldn't reproduce your result:

Input data looks OK:

```
> print(items)
Date A B C D
1 1-2010 0 0 0 1
2 2-2010 0 0 1 2
3 3-2010 1 1 0 0
```

Nothing unexpected here:

```
> data_test <- NULL
> print(data_test)
NULL

> for(i in 1:ncol(items)) {
+   col <- ts(items[,i])
+   fit1 <- auto.arima(col, trace=TRUE)
+   fcast <- forecast(fit1,h=12, level=c(90,95))
+ data_test <- cbind(data_test, fcast$lower)
+ }
```

col contains, as expected, result of the last call of of ts:

```
> print(col)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 3 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 1 2 0
```

Input data look untouched:

```
> print(items)
    Date A B C D
1 1-2010 0 0 0 1
2 2-2010 0 0 1 2
3 3-2010 1 1 0 0
```

And the output:

```
> print(data_test)
            90%       95%        90%        95%        90%        95%
 [1,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.7020735 -0.8420231 -0.7020735 -0.8420231
 [2,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.3839978 -0.5337011 -0.3839978 -0.5337011
 [3,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.5312107 -0.6822689 -0.5312107 -0.6822689
 [4,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4790011 -0.6302537 -0.4790011 -0.6302537
 [5,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4993618 -0.6506425 -0.4993618 -0.6506425
 [6,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4917056 -0.6429903 -0.4917056 -0.6429903
 [7,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4946245 -0.6459098 -0.4946245 -0.6459098
 [8,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4935175 -0.6448029 -0.4935175 -0.6448029
 [9,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4939381 -0.6452235 -0.4939381 -0.6452235
[10,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4937784 -0.6450638 -0.4937784 -0.6450638
[11,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4938391 -0.6451245 -0.4938391 -0.6451245
[12,] 0.6569826 0.3996961 -0.4938160 -0.6451014 -0.4938160 -0.6451014
             90%       95%         90%         95%
 [1,] -0.9496567 -1.131586  1.42604280  1.27350002
 [2,] -0.9496567 -1.131586 -0.64967538 -0.84765489
 [3,] -0.9496567 -1.131586  0.73647195  0.51264884
 [4,] -0.9496567 -1.131586 -0.60589544 -0.84580765
 [5,] -0.9496567 -1.131586  0.38080673  0.13047778
 [6,] -0.9496567 -1.131586 -0.51643718 -0.77365275
 [7,] -0.9496567 -1.131586  0.17206486 -0.08975985
 [8,] -0.9496567 -1.131586 -0.43367240 -0.69860560
 [9,] -0.9496567 -1.131586  0.04304077 -0.22399916
[10,] -0.9496567 -1.131586 -0.36792524 -0.63639759
[11,] -0.9496567 -1.131586 -0.03920847 -0.30865684
[12,] -0.9496567 -1.131586 -0.31885153 -0.58896591
```

Only thing is that you should probably omit first column (for(i in 2:ncol(items))) because fitting dates labels is a little bit pointless, isn't it?

Comment: Strange. When I'm working with the data I provided in this question I get the same result as you. However, in my actual-dataset it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Tho be honest in the first version of the question you had quite a messy code. Are you sure that something else (maybe before or after the loop) is messing with your data?

Comment: could it be that my first row (date) is defined as row.names? or maybe something with 'attr(,"levels")[1] 0 0 1'.  otherwise I have no idea